# Respond with files when log in

Tags: html, node.js, express

Hi guys what I´m trying to do, is add another component to the website like text buttons, so changed slightly, the file that I Want to change when login the is WEBSITE file inside the FOLDER1 folder.

`- FOLDER1
         |_WEBSITE.
 - SIGN IN
         |_ SIGN IN SITE.
 - PUBLIC
          |_ ALL THE STATIC FILES.
 - SERVER.JS(where the gets a post are located).`

I have tried to add another static files and response.sendFile with the desired web page file, changed inside else in Credential.findOne for the mongoDB database.

```
app.post("/signin/signin.html", function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    Credential.findOne({user: email, password: password}, function(err, 
    foundLList) {
        if(err) {

        } else {

        }
      }
    ); 
 });
```

What I´m trying to do is change the look of the website (WEBSITE file) adding text and buttons, how do I do it?.

Comment: Can you post more code, such as your app.js/www.js file? What view engine are you using for Express?

Comment: I don't understand your question correctly but.. I think you should look at some templating engine. That way you could have 1 page and based on passed condition you could change the behavior of your page. Anyways if you have another folder with the file you should use res.sendFile(path_to_file).

Comment: @MFK34 sorry for not explaining myself what I´m trying to do is when it logins successfully change the design of the WEBSITE file, the app.post is in the server.js file

Comment: I would suggest you should look into templating engine (jinja or check out this link has list of engines with express https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html). If you don't want to do that why don't you just redirect the user to your changed page. It would be much simpler just a simple redirect?